# Is there any way to get MAC address of elastic network interface?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is there any way to get MAC address of  elastic network interface  of aws, using aws JAVA SDk

Comment: For what purpose? They're not very useful things.

Comment: I just need it , Is there any way have checked out there api docs it was not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the MAC address using AWS-CLI using `describe-network-interfaces` command as below:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-eaxxxxd | jq ".NetworkInterfaces[].MacAddress"
"06:56:88:b9:82:17"
```

ALso in Ruby-SDK, there is a way to pull the MAC address using [describe_network_interfaces-instance_method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/V20130615.html#describe_network_interfaces-instance_method)

I searched the JAVA SDK documentation for [DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest.html) and seems it does provides mac address. However, I am not good at reading JAVA API Documentation.

As I was able to get the MAC address using AWS-CLI and RUBY-SDK, the API is in place. Just that you need to get the exact method in JAVA-SDK documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get network interface of instance and from that get mac address
                List<InstanceNetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = inst.getNetworkInterfaces();
                for (InstanceNetworkInterface instanceNetworkInterface : networkInterfaces) {
                    System.out.println("=-------------"+instanceNetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaceId());


                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest describeNetworkInterfacesRequest = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesRequest();
                    describeNetworkInterfacesRequest.withNetworkInterfaceIds(instanceNetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaceId());
                    DescribeNetworkInterfacesResult describeNetworkInterfacesResult = amazonEc2.describeNetworkInterfaces(describeNetworkInterfacesRequest);
                    List<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces1 = describeNetworkInterfacesResult.getNetworkInterfaces();
                    for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : networkInterfaces1) {
                        System.out.println(networkInterface.getMacAddress());

                    }
                }
                //-------------------------
```